# Matrial UI change border of outlined select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the default outline color of the Select component in Material UI.

This is what I've tried but did not work:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
    borderColor:  "green",
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  outlined: {
    '&:before': {
        borderColor: "green",
    },
    '&:after': {
        borderColor:  "green",
    }
},
}));

export default function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = event => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Age"
          className={classes.outlined}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

P.S. This is how it looks when focused/selected [image: default]

Answer (score 0):

Try with deep nesting or with important.

```
borderColor:  "green !important",
```